# Learning curve is the same for training and validation?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I've been training a neural network with scikit-learn's MLPRegressor using ShuffleSplit with 10 splits and 20% of the data set aside for testing. First I use GridSearchCV to find good parameters. I then instantiate a new (unfitted) estimator with those params, and finally use the [plot_learning_curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html) function, with a MAPE scorer and the same ShuffleSplit cv.

In most of the learning curve examples I've seen, the validation and training curves are distinctly separate. However, I've consistently been getting learning curves where the cross validation and training curve are almost identical. How should I interpet this - does it seem realistic, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

[Learning Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG6Cu.png)

As requested, here's the code:

```
node_range = list(range(1,16))
layer_range = range(1,6)
hidden_sizes = [(nodes,) * layers for layers in layer_range for nodes in node_range]

param_grid = [{'hidden_layer_sizes': hidden_sizes,
               'activation': ['relu'],
               'learning_rate_init': [0.5]}
              ]

cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.2)

search = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid, cv=cv, scoring=neg_MAPE, refit=True)
search.fit(X, y)
best_params = search.best_params_
estimator = MLPRegressor().set_params(**best_params)

plot_learning_curve(estimator, X, y, cv=cv, scoring=neg_MAPE)
```

And here is my scorer:

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

neg_MAPE = make_scorer(mean_absolute_percentage_error, greater_is_better=False)
```

Comment: If you post the code that created the plot, it's more likely that someone can help you.

Comment: I posted a link to the plot_learning_curve method in my original post. Added code to show what arguments I'm passing through, hope that's more clear

Comment: What is the dimension of your X?  Are you scaling it beforehand?